# Tensorflow Bibliography

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to learn how to work with tensorflow.

My background is somewhat a mathematical one, but I know how to program in Mathematica, Python and R.

I'm looking for some bibliography focused only on Tensorflow. I've searched, and there are so many possibilities, but I simply don't have the knowledge to assess either the publisher, the authors, the content.

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/29957/28175).